# Can you DROP the 'sys' database in MySQL workbench or does it have to be there?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have just started using [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) for the first time and I noticed there is a 'sys' database already in there.

[image: sys DB]

Does anybody know if this has to be there? or can I just DROP it?

Not sure if dropping this will break anything, thanks!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sys-schema.html

Comment: Why do you need to delete that? You need that. don't drop it!

Comment: Read the notes, thanks! The initial MySQL course I just took never even mentioned it! Something to feedback to the course.

Comment: DO NOT DROP IT!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Can you DROP the 'sys' database

yes

> or does it have to be there?

no

> will break anything

Some monitoring tools may depend on the schema.

Answer (score -1):

**ANSWERED**

> MySQL 8.0 includes the sys schema, a set of objects that helps DBAs and developers interpret data collected by the Performance Schema. sys schema objects can be used for typical tuning and diagnosis use cases. Objects in this schema include:
>
> Views that summarize Performance Schema data into more easily understandable form.
>
> Stored procedures that perform operations such as Performance Schema configuration and generating diagnostic reports.
> Stored functions that query Performance Schema configuration and provide formatting services.

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sys-schema.html) for reference.